Unable to run Ubuntu guest with VirtualBox
I'm having hard time to create a virtual machine with VirtualBox for Ubuntu guest.
I tried:

Ubuntu 24.04 as host on desktop
Ubuntu 24.04 as host on laptop
Windows 11 as host on desktop
Ubuntu 24.04 as guest
Ubuntu 23.10 as guest

I'm using the latest VirtualBox available on their web site (v7.0.20).
For each installation I tried to change the following parameters:

screen adapter (VMSVGA, VBoxVGA, VBoxSVGA)
enable/disable 3D acceleration
change the virtualization settings
enable/disable wayland

In all cases the Ubuntu guest is unstable and unreliable. It takes long time to open a window, and after few minutes the machine will hangs, and even "turn off machine" does not work. Of course I also installed the guest additions.
Since I changed the host, the guest and the hardware configuration (desktop and mobile, both with modern components) I'm running out of ideas. I use VirtualBox from 10+ years and I never ran in such a trouble.
I guess the culprit is the following message that is written hundreds of times in dmesg:

[drm:vmw_msg_ioctl [vmwgfx]] ERROR Failed to open channel.

Looking on the Internet I found a lot of hints to try this or that (usually the options I described above).
Is there a way to understand the root of the issue in order to fix it?

Have you installed the guest additions?

If you could share info on your host CPUs, that might help. Note that 10 years ago, not only was virtualbox different, but also Ubuntu. If you want to share info on your CPU, head -n50 /proc/cpuinfo| curl -F 'file=@-' https://0x0.st uploads that to a server, and gives you a link to it that you can show to us.

"I guess the culprit is the following message that is written hundreds of times in dmesg:", nah that seems very innocent.
